# RxJS return empty promise but continue chain

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I have a http service that I need to call depending on the users input.

```
saveImage(): Observable<Photo> {
    if (!this.squaredImage) {
        return Observable.of();
    }

    this.photoCreateDto = {
        sourcePhoto: this.sourceImage,
        squaredPhoto: this.squaredImage,
        fileExtension: this.fileExtension
    };

    return this.photoService.createPhoto(this.photoCreateDto);
}
```

I call `saveImage` from another save function:

```
save() {
    this.saveImage().subscribe((newPhoto: Photo) => {

         .. never gets here

    });
}
```

If `this.squaredImage` has no value and the empty promise is returned, the chain ends. If the `createPhoto` service is called, it continues. I have also tried returning `Observable.empty()`. How do you handle this scenario in rxjs?

Comment: So what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want the callback of `saveImage` to be called every time. I think I am incorrectly comparing this to a `then` promise chain and am trying to return an empty promise.

Comment: Then you need to return an observable that emits a value. Not an empty one. The subscribe callback is called for each emitted event. So if you never emit an event, it is never called.

Comment: @JBNizet Does `Observable.of` not construct an observable of one value?

Comment: @Bergi it does if you pass an argument to the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're handling only the `next` notifications with:

```
this.saveImage().subscribe((newPhoto: Photo) => { ... });
```

... while `Observable.of()` or `Observable.empty()` don't emit any `next` (they just send `complete` notifications).

So one thing you can do is to emit for example `null` and then in the subscriber check what value you sent:

```
saveImage(): Observable<Photo> {
    if (!this.squaredImage) {
        return Observable.of(null);
    }
    ...
}

...

this.saveImage().subscribe((newPhoto: Photo) => {
    if (newPhoto === null) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
})
```

Or you can listen to both `next` and `complete` notifications (but be aware that when you return `this.photoService.createPhoto` a `complete` notification is probably sent as well):

```
this.saveImage().subscribe({
  next: (newPhoto: Photo) => {...}
  complete: () => { ... }
})
```

Comment: explain precise!